# Scrambled video when using dash in Unity 14.04.3

Tags: 14.04, unity, nvidia, unity-dash

On a Trusty 14.04.3 LTS (running otherwise very smoothly), opening `dash` from the launch-bar or from the keyboard, causes the video signal on the corresponding display to go berserk. I have two displays and only the one with the launch-bar is affected. Viz [screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/r91rp4b8ovu9r5w/20150831_dash_screenshot.jpg?dl=0). Subsequently closing `dash` suppresses the problem altogether. This makes `dash` completely unusable.

The scrambled visual is not fixed but changes with average frequency 1 Hz. While the one display runs crazy the other one is fine and I can continue working on it as if nothing was happening. So my GPU is fine. This is an x86 based HP box.

From terminal:

```
$ uname -r
3.16.0-46-generic
$ unity --version
unity 7.2.5
$ lspci -nn | grep VGA
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation G84GLM [Quadro FX 570M] [10de:040c] (rev a1)
```

Earlier today I had done, from terminal, `sudo apt-get upgrade` which resulted in the upgrade of `freshplayerplugin`from ppa and:

```
...
Removing linux-headers-3.13.0-61-generic (3.13.0-61.100) ...
Removing linux-headers-3.13.0-61 (3.13.0-61.100) ...
Removing linux-image-extra-3.13.0-61-generic (3.13.0-61.100)
...
```

I have since then purged `freshplayerplugin`, and ran `sudo apt-get autoremove` to rebuild a clean grub2 menu.

I use `X.Org X server - Nouveau Display driver` and I have not changed anything recently, in my GPU driver config . Could it still be a driver problem related to a recent kernel release ? (I have the auto-update enabled for security releases).

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After selecting the `NVIDIA binary driver - version 340.76 from nvidia-340 (proprietary, tested)` for my GPU, I restarted my box and the problem went away.

I surmise that after a kernel version minor update (perhaps requiring a restart, but I did not see that recommendation), the `dash` shell's gui's old dependencies were somehow not met when using the `X.Org X server Nouveau Display Driver`. That however strikes me as odd and it may not have anything to do with one driver or another.